# Azure Keyvault Certificate Disabled and unable to Enable

Tags: azure

I generated a new self signed certificate via Keyvault>Certificates. However I subsequently wanted to move the certificate to a different Keyvault (in same subscription and resource group). This I ascertained was not possible but looked like it could be down by Backup and Restore. I have restored the Certificate into the new Keyvault and the original Keyvault was deleted. However the restored certificate is listed under IN PROGRESS, FAILED OR CANCELLED and says its status is Disabled. I am unable to enable the certificate. Selecting it shows the restored (Disabled) certificate under Current versions and underneath that it shows Older versions were the original certificate is shown enabled. If i try to enable the current one the Save button remains greyed out. Enabling or Disabling the older one doesn't have any effect. Anyone able to suggest anything? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Certificates become enabled once you bind them to service and start using them.

E.g. in Web App you can choose to "Import Key Vault Certificate" from "TLS/SSL settings" tab. You can then bind certificate to a custom domain under "TLS/SSL bindings".